# When should we use Absolute Deviance Residual Plot or Deviance Residual Plot?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-visualization, residuals

My lecturer mentioned that Absolute Deviance Residual Plot is better to use than the Deviance Residual Plot when analyzing fit of model in the GLM process. I was wondering what do you guys think about that? What are benefits of the Absolute Deviance Residual Plot over the Deviance Residual Plot?